# Значение dots в owl carousel

Tags: javascript, битрикс, owl-carousel, слайдер, dots

Скачал шаблон сайта с [W3layouts templates](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/)

Есть слайдер, сделанный с помощью owl carousel.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно сделать dots для owl-carousel в виде прямоугольника (как на скриншоте)?

Comment: попробуйте с помощью css